# How to produce a near csv format using xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xsl file to produce the cd data in csv format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/catalog">

    <xsl:for-each select="cd">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:if test="position()  = last()"><xsl:value-of select="./child::*"/>,   </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="position()  = last()"><xsl:value-of select="./child::year"/>&#xD;
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the sample data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Red</title>
    <artist>The Communards</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>London</company>
    <price>7.80</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Unchain my heart</title>
    <artist>Joe Cocker</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>EMI</company>
    <price>8.20</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

each time i run the program on oxygen i get a miserable format: How to adjust the output to produce a csv format?

Comment: If you want text output like CSV I would start with using `<xsl:output method="text"/>`. Beyond that it is not clear which exact result you want for that input and, given that you mention oXygen, why you restrict yourself to XSLT 1 while XSLT 2 with `xsl:value-of select="*" separator=","` has a neat instruction to output items with a certain separator.

Answer (score 1):

For CSV output, you need to specify `<xsl:output method="text"/>` in the XSLT. If you are looking for an output containing `comma` separated values of all the child elements of `<cd>`, you can use any one of the below approaches.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="cd">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()" >
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="position() = last()" >
                <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

This version provides a more optimal solution with the additional features that it comes with.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="cd">
        <xsl:value-of select="*" separator=", " />
        <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
Red, The Communards, UK, London, 7.80, 1987
Unchain my heart, Joe Cocker, USA, EMI, 8.20, 1987
```